# What are MINIMAL necessary reqirements to run Perl CGI scripts on Apache server?

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, perl, cgi

I have my Apache showing perl scripts as plaint text, not executing them. Googling and playing with settings made me frustrating, because there are numerous and long samples, which are mostly ignored by my server.

The question is: what are absolutely necessary minimal requirements to run Perl CGI scripts on my web site?

Please no security issues, no other issues, only running Perl.

Currently I have `Apache2` installed, `mod_perl` installed, `perl` installed, virtual hosts installed, execution permission granted.

And I have `index.cgi` is displayed as plain text.

The following is my size config:

[image]

One special question is: why `AddHandler` directive is silently ignored twice? If it was explicitly said, that `.cgi` files should be handled by `cgi-script`, then how this can be silently ignored (no any warning in logs).

From my point of view, any directive should be either executed or caused an error. It can't just hang in the air as if it was no any directive at all.

**UPDATE**

The files are Bugzilla installation. I.e. there are plenty of `*.cgi` files with perl code inside.

Comment: Is the generated HTML code shown as plain text or the perl code? Did you really mean `*.GCI` or did you mean `*.cgi`?

Comment: Perl code is displayed. I meant lowercase.

Comment: And I guess you also meant `*.cgi` instead of `*.gci`. (Now lowercase so the second difference can be spotted more easily, too.) Hrm.

Answer (score 0):

mod_perl isn't necessary to run Perl CGI scripts in Apache. (But it may speed up some of them.)

What may be missing but isn't clear due to the rather incomplete configuration shown above, is, if mod_cgid or mod_cgi are loaded. In Apache 2.2, it depends on the MPM which of those two you have to use.

If you're on Debian or Ubuntu, calling `a2enmod cgi` or `a2enmod cgid` plus a `service apache2 restart` may already suffice to solve your issue. Not sure if these helper scripts are available on other distributions, too.